# How to modify the params that rails use to pull object from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, primary-key

Sorry about the title, it's really hard to explain but I'll try my best to make it as clear as possible.

So, I have this app that I am building sort of 'Social Shift Trading Network'. So in this app I have a calendar(fullcalendar-rails) that I use, and I generate shifts using a model but I realise that the id generated automatically by the database tend to not be useful when there are a lot of deletion of object or changes because the index is not being reset. So, I thought that I would put a shift_id column in my Shift model and generate id with SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8).

But how do I set it as a primary key so that when I edit or call show on it for it to use shift_id as params?

I tried set :id => false, and set :primary => :shift_id but still no result. I believe because my route format is "/shifts/:id/edit(.:format)" formatted to pull :id that it does not work.

Thank for you for any help in advance.

```
class CreateShifts < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :shifts, {:id => false, :primary_key => :shift_id}   do |t|
  t.string :position
  t.datetime :date
  t.datetime :start_time
  t.datetime :finish_time
  t.integer :original_owner
  t.integer :current_owner
  t.string   :shift_id 
  t.string :shift_posted, :default => "Not Posted"

  t.timestamps
end
```

end

Comment: I don't understand why you need to add a shift_id column when there's already a PK column called id that is automatically generated for you (and which you presumably intend to use in the same way as shift_id). What do you mean by "id generated automatically by the database tend to not be useful when there are a lot of deletion."

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is correct, all you want is that the URL becomes something like this

```
/shifts/:some_random_hash/edit
```

To do that you don't need to mess your database like that, just generate that normal table, and add that `:shift_id` field, then tell the model which field to use for the url.

```
class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  to_param
    shift_id
  end
end
```

This way when you use `url_for` or `shift_path` the model will use the `:shift_id` instead to generate that URL, but internally it would use the auto increment id

Comment: Thank you,  will give it a try , the reason im doing this is when I delete an object for example and something goes wrong the index is not resetted or when I trade shift between users, and one of their shift index went wrong its giving me a hard time. Because for instance, it will try to pull 8th index but the shift id is 7..

Comment: by shift index you mean shift_id ?

Comment: No sorry, I mean the id that the database use so it would just be id

Comment: These index are supposed to be unique and auto incremented, even if a record is deleted, the next record doesn't take the deleted ID unless you force it to use it

Comment: Thats where I cant wrap my head around it.. then why would it try to retrieve an id 8 if the id that It should be retrieving is 7 .. anyway I will try to have a look at it again and edit this once I figure out what Im doing wrong. Thanks Mohammad

Comment: you could add the code snippet that's misbehaving and I'll check where things might be going wrong